# How do I filter firebase databse based on checkbox value in anular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have an event page where all events get displayed and all events have a category field. My database looks something like this:

```
category:
  -categoryName

events:
  - evenName
  - category.id (I have stored id of category)
```

first of all, I want to display all events and when the user clicks on checkboxes I want to display events based on the checked box value also if the user unselects it then display all events again.
please help I'm new in angular

**Thank you :)**

**events.service.ts**

```
categories = null;
subscription;

/** Get Categories */
  getEventCategories() {
    if (!this.categories) {
      this.subscription = this.db
        .collection('categories')
        .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
        .subscribe(categories => (this.categories = categories));
    }
  }

/** Get Category Vise Events */
  getCategoryViseEvents(category: string) {
    return this.db
      .collection('events', ref => ref.where('eventCategory', '==', category))
      .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
  }
```

**event.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventsService } from 'src/app/services/events.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events-list',
  templateUrl: './events-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events-list.component.css']
})
export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit {
  events: any;
  mobile = false;
  loading = true;

  constructor(public eventService: EventsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (window.screen.width === 375) {
      // 768px portrait
      this.mobile = true;
    }

    this.eventService.getEventCategories();
    this.eventService.getAllEvents().subscribe(ev => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.events = ev;
    })
  }

  getCategory($event) {
    this.loading = true;
    if ($event.target.checked) {
      this.eventService.getCategoryViseEvents($event.target.id).subscribe(events => {
        this.events = events;
        this.loading = false;
      })
    } else {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
}
```

**event.component.html

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  class="custom-control-input"
  [id]="category.id"
  (change)="getCategory($event)"/>
```

Comment: Would it be ok for you to first fetch all the data in a list, and then keep this list, and then filter the list (without querying firebase after the first query ?)

Comment: It's ok, but I don't know how to do that :(

Answer (score 1):

Create an object call **allEvents** in your service. I don't see your function `getAllEvents` but it should load its own result in **allEvents** before returning it. (For this you can subscribe to the observable 2 times, once in the service, and once in the component)

**events.service.ts**

```
categories = null;
subscription;
allEvents: Array<any> = [] // In here you will store your events in getAllEvents

/** Get Categories */
  getEventCategories(sendCategoriesCallback: function) {
    if (!this.categories) {
      this.subscription = this.db
        .collection('categories')
        .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
        .subscribe(categories => {
            this.categories = categories
            sendCategoriesCallback(this.categories)
        });
    }
  }

/** Get Category Vise Events */
  getCategoryViseEvents(category: string) {
    return this.allEvents.filter(event => event.category == category)
  }
```

**event.component.ts**

As you can see here I almost erased all of you **getCategoryVise..** because the **filter** doesn't return an Observable anymore (it's instant).

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventsService } from 'src/app/services/events.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events-list',
  templateUrl: './events-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events-list.component.css']
})
export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit {
  events: any;
  mobile = false;
  loading = true;

  constructor(public eventService: EventsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (window.screen.width === 375) {
      // 768px portrait
      this.mobile = true;
    }

    this.eventService.getEventCategories((categories) => {
        this.categories = categories
    });

    this.eventService.getAllEvents().subscribe(ev => {
      this.loading = false;
      this.events = ev;
    })
  }

  getCategory($event) {
    this.loading = true;
    if ($event.target.checked) {
    this.events = this.eventService.getCategoryViseEvents($event.target.id)
  }
}
```

**event.component.html

I added ***ngFor** instruction here

```
<input
  *ngFor="let category of categories"
  type="checkbox"
  class="custom-control-input"
  [id]="category.id"
  (change)="getCategory($event)"/>
```